# CSS Issues with Div Height

Tags: html, css

So here's my code:

```
#logo {
position:fixed;
color: white;
width: 100%;
padding: 5px;
left:0px;
top:0px;
height:50px;
width:100%;
background:#ffffff;
z-index: 1;
}

#page-container {
margin: auto;
width: 960px;
height: 100%!important;
background: #ffffff;
border-style: solid;
border-color: red;

}

html, body {

padding: 0;
}

body {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
color: #000000;
background-color: #eef3f7;
}

#footer {
position:fixed!important;
position:absolute;
color: white;
clear: both;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
left:0px;
bottom:0px;
height:30px;
background:#272695;
text-align:center;
}
```

I want to be able to set the page container height so that the footer over laps it all the way through. The issue I am getting is this:

[image: ScreenCap]

What I want is to have my page-content rule to cover the whole top and bottom with no overlapping. I'm looking for something along the lines of this:

[image: Mock Up]

I honestly have tried everything I just don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Could you post your HTML code as well ?

Comment: As @Eria has said, posting your html somewhere for us to look at is needed.

Comment: It's hard to understand what your objective is, _"I want to be able to set the page container height so that the footer over laps it all the way through."_ Is a bit unclear. Are you asking about a [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/)?

Comment: Let me get this to a jsfiddle then.

Comment: @Eria I'm still working on it, seems that jsfiddle lost my navigation bar, but that is working just fine. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/talentless_hack/tthuc7wx/2/)I hope this helps[/linkl]

Comment: Your question is still unclear. I see what you're asking being done in the JSFiddle. The _"...footer overlaps it all the way through."_

Comment: @hungerstar, I don't want my page-content div to end, I want it to keep going under the footer. 

Putting the page content div in a fixed position makes it so I can't scroll down.

Comment: @talentless_hack Still making sense, though I understand (sort of) after Andrew's answer. On a side note, you have a lot of depreciated or obsolete markup along with a few poor practices. Not being mean, just hoping to get you on the right track. Today's sites shouldn't use the [`<font> tag`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font), or the `align` attribute. Please avoid using `<br>` tags and `&nbsp;` as layout and positioning devices. All these things can be fixed with the proper application of CSS.

Comment: @hungerstar That's mainly because this is just the rough draft. I will be taking those out once I get the actual content ready. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: @talentless_hack right on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS.

```
body, html {
   height: 100%;
}
```

The CSS height property is relative to it's parent and height defaults to `auto`.  So to get your #page-container to be 100% you have to set the parent height.

Comment: Oh I get it, Thanks!